# How to make moving blur effect on Gimp

Tags: gimp, blur

I like to make a moving blur on a picture using GIMP (on Ubuntu). What kind of effects should I use? I already use blur but it doesn't give the moving blur.

Note: I'm beginner in graphic design

Comment: I think you mean "motion blur"?

Comment: @OlleSjögren Yes, it is motion blur. I don't know the ordinary name so I use moving blur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add Motion blur: Select **Blur** from the **Filters** menu, then **Motion Blur**. You can select to add blur from linear, radial, and/or zoom movements.